# Number of controllers per view and how to assign to views?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I am seeking some feedback about controllers and views.

Currently I am using 1 x controller per view. So the controller is in charge of a entire view.

I know you are able to put ng-controller for parts of the view i.e. assigning to divs. This way an entire view might by managed by more than 1 controller.

What is the advisable way of doing this? Using 1 controller or using more than one controller.

I have my controllers structured so they appear under the functionality type so I assume adding more controllers under that directory to keep things organized would work.

Although I am confused what I should be doing. Let's face it, there is always a right and a wrong way to do it and recommended.

What route should I be taking?

Comment: I try to keep functionality in each controller directly relevant to the name of the controller and the contents of the HTML tag. For instance I have a `chatLogController` that handles events to update a chat log, and in the chatlog html, a repeater `message in messages`. Each repeated item has a `messageController` with message-specific stuff like `$scope.deleteMessage()`. Functionality that is needed in more than one controller, I put in a service. Values that are needed in more than one controller, I attach to `$rootScope`.

Comment: Plato, from my understanding angular recommends avoiding the use of rootScope and instead using a service.  Is there a reason you prefer rootScope?

Answer (score 0):

Please visit below url.

http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/controllers/sharing-models-between-nested-controllers.html

Let me know if any question

Answer (score 0):

You should be generally using one controller per view and peppering each view with custom directives which contain their own controllers. Nested controllers will complicate things. Using directives encapsulates it.